# Client is not permitted to perform this action STTwitter Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sttwitter

I am using STTWitter for login using twitter. I have created an app.

When I try to call login method I am getting this error:

```
 Error Domain=STTwitterTwitterErrorDomain Code=87 "
 Client is not permitted to perform this action"
```

I am using this method to login:

```
STTwitterAPI *twitter = [STTwitterAPI twitterAPIWithOAuthConsumerKey:@"sqsamplekeyzWcESlRq3h"
                                                      consumerSecret:@"pgs0nD4qconsumeersecretkeyjOOzLk83obgw2s341WHlQ"
                                                            username:@"username"
                                                            password:@"password"];



[twitter verifyCredentialsWithUserSuccessBlock:^(NSString *username, NSString *userID) {

    NSLog(@"YES");
    // ...
} errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
    // ...
}];
```

Comment: This is probably because your Twitter app is not Reverse Auth enabled, see https://twittercommunity.com/t/ios-reverse-auth-step-two-request-issue/5932 for instance